# Using NSIS possible to access Windows's public folder "c:\Users\Public"

Tags: nsis

How do I obtain the Public folder path using NSIS script? Is there a Constant similar to $SMPROGRAMS. 
I need to install my software under "C:\Users\Public\companyname\appname"

I am looking for something like the below,

```
SetShellVarContext all
StrCpy $INSTDIR "$PUBLIC\${COMPANYNAME}\${APPNAME}"
```

where the $PUBLIC picks up the OS dependent public folder.

Comment: Why do you think you need to install an application in the public folder?

Comment: My application consists of executables and shared documents and currently all residing under 'Program Files'. One of the executable has to be run with an elevated privilege in order to install a plugin. My application also has shared documents  that a user may open up in the executable (run in non-adminstrative mode) and edit them. Upon editing, copy of the documents end up in 'windows Virtual Store'. The shared documents have to be available for all users. So I am in the process of changing the current installation folder to  %Public% or %ProgramData% or both for different components.

Comment: You should fix the application if possible. $ProgramFiles is the correct place for applications.

Comment: Thanks you. I'll consider keeping my application in $ProgramFiles. I have a folder, in which the files, subfolders contain header files(of a library) that can be opened by my application and and there is the possibility of modifying (will eventually end up in VirtualStore).  I would like keep this folder, subfolder and their files as READONLY. I couldn't find any usage of 'SetFileAttributes' to perform on a folder recursively? Sorry if this, needs to be raised as a different question in this forum.

Comment: Yes, ask a new question for that. But you should try to resolve this question first.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Vista `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` is `%SystemDrive%\ProgramData`. Some of the things that used to be under `All Users` were moved to `%Public%` and the rest are in `%ProgramData%`.

The `%Public%` folder contains the folders for shared documents, pictures, music and video. You can access these in NSIS by switching to the "all context":

```
SetShellVarContext All
DetailPrint $Documents
DetailPrint $Pictures
DetailPrint $Music
DetailPrint $Videos
```

NSIS does not provide direct access to the `%Public%` folder and it is **not** a location where you should install applications!

You should only use the `%Public%` path if you have invented a new folder type that makes sense to be exposed to and shared by multiple users:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section
!define /IfNDef FOLDERID_Public {DFDF76A2-C82A-4D63-906A-5644AC457385}
System::Call 'SHELL32::SHGetKnownFolderPath(g"${FOLDERID_Public}",i0x1000,p0,*p.r1)i.r0'
${If} $0 = 0
    System::Call '*$1(&w${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}.r0)'
    System::Call 'OLE32::CoTaskMemFree(pr1)'
    DetailPrint "FOLDERID_Public=$0"
${Else}
    DetailPrint "FOLDERID_Public does not exist on < Vista"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```